# jQuery branching backwards button

Tags: jquery, branch, wizard

I am working with a built jQuery Wizard on this site: http://kflorence.github.com/jquery-wizard/examples/ and the one I am working with is the "Branching Wizard." Based on your selections, you will go to different questions/answers.

My problem is I built the wizard with about 4 questions so far, but when you hit the "Backwards" button you only go back once. I want to be able to keep clicking the "Backwards" button to go through all the previous questions I went through.

I am guessing this is the section of the code I need to edit? I just can't figure it out:

```
select: function( event, step, branch, relative, history ) {

    // args: step, branch, relative, history
    if ( !( event instanceof $.Event ) ) {
        history = relative;
        relative = branch;
        branch = step;
        step = event;
        event = undefined;
    }

    if ( step == undefined ) {
        return;
    }

    // args: [ step, branch ], relative, history
    if ( $.isArray( step ) ) {
        history = relative;
        relative = branch;
        branch = step[ 1 ];
        step = step[ 0 ];

    // args: step, relative, history
    } else if ( typeof branch === bool ) {
        history = relative;
        relative = branch;
        branch = undefined;
    }

    this._move( step, branch, relative, history, function( stepIndex, stepsTaken ) {
        this._update( event, this._state( stepIndex, stepsTaken ) );
    });
},
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Kokos, I have discovered that this works fine in Firefox, but does NOT work in Internet Explorer!! Anyone have even the slightest idea how to get it to work in IE?

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your problem, but the back buttons work fine on all questions for me.

Comment: Well it seems that the wizard works fine in Firefox, but NOT in IE8. Great... now how do I fix that problem.

Comment: Maybe http://www.impressivewebs.com/7-javascript-differences-between-firefox-ie/ can help.

Comment: That page doesn't look like it has what I am looking for. I have no idea why IE won't let you use the back button more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This has since been fixed in this revision: https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-wizard/issues/4